# Filtering a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this,

```python
[Row(cardholder_nbr=u'10', category_nbr=87, club_nbr=6279, membership_nbr=u'780941902', retail_all=51.23, sub_category_nbr=1, system_item_nbr=3572924, unit_qty=1.0, visit_date=u'2016-08-05', visit_nbr=1608057826021405)]
```

I want to  filter it based on a visit date range between say 2016-09-15 to 2016-09-23. 
How do I do it?
If I do it like this,

```python
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from df_table WHERE visit_date >= '2016-09-15' AND visit_date <= '2016-09-23'")
```

I get this error,

> "invalid literal for int()"

How do I filter it properly?

Comment: Did you use a UDF on your dataframe before this filtering ?

Comment: Nope. I am afraid I did not.

Comment: what version of spark?, this actually works for me in 2.0

Comment: data = [Row(cardholder_nbr=u'10', category_nbr=87, club_nbr=6279, membership_nbr=u'780941902',
            retail_all=51.23, sub_category_nbr=1, system_item_nbr=3572924, unit_qty=1.0, visit_date=u'2016-08-05', 
            visit_nbr=1608057826021405)]
 // df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF()
 // df.registerTempTable('df')
//  sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from df WHERE visit_date >= '2016-09-15' AND visit_date <= '2016-09-23'").show()

Comment: Spark Version I am using is 1.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this and let us know if it works?

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

data = [Row(cardholder_nbr=u'10', category_nbr=87, club_nbr=6279, membership_nbr=u'780941902', retail_all=51.23, sub_category_nbr=1, system_item_nbr=3572924, unit_qty=1.0, visit_date=u'2016-08-05', visit_nbr=1608057826021405),
        Row(cardholder_nbr=u'10', category_nbr=87, club_nbr=6279, membership_nbr=u'780941902', retail_all=51.23, sub_category_nbr=1, system_item_nbr=3572924, unit_qty=1.0, visit_date=u'2016-09-16', visit_nbr=1608057826021405)]
df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF()
df.show()
df.where((f.col("visit_date") >= '2016-09-15') & (f.col("visit_date") <= '2016-09-23')).show()
```